# How to support absolute path imports in React Server Side Rendering?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, server-side-rendering

I am trying to implement Server Side Rendering for my React application and I have stumbled across a problem related to absolute path imports of my components. When I try to run the server I get an error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'components/Header/Header.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/crs/Desktop/app/src/App.js:4:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Module._compile (/Users/crs/Desktop/app/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:99:24)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (/Users/crs/Desktop/app/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:104:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
```

In the server I use the `renderToString` function from the ReactDOM library on the `<App />` component.

```
....
return res.send(
      data.replace(
        '<div id="root"></div>',
        `<div id="root">${ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<App />)}</div>`
      )
    );
....
```

The `<App />` component on the other hand has only a header and a footer component.

```
import React from "react";
import Header from "components/Header/Header.js";
import Footer from "components/Footer/Footer";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header/>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

The import statements work when I run the code with the `react-sripts-start`, because of the `jsconfig.json` I have on my root directory but now the imports are giving an error on the server.

Is there a babel plugin or another method to fix this?

Comment: 'components/Header/Header.js' where you are importing it .share some code may be you are not giving right path.you need to share your folder structure for that.

Comment: @PrakashKarena updated the question with some more code. The code is working just fine when I didn't use React-SSR. A jsconfig.json file I had took care of absolute imports, but on the server it is giving a problem.

Comment: What are you using for building SSR?

Comment: Since this question got some attention lately I ended up using https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver.

Comment: @DavidPrifti can you tell how did you solve this issue? i visited this link you've given but could not find my answer. Did you replace your jsconfig with .babelrc or what?